# How to pass RxNumber in FHIR 'MedicationRequest' resource?

Tags: hl7-fhir

I am not sure if the 'RxNumber' should be part of the incoming 'MedicationRequest' or not. I would like to know how people are treating RxNumber in this FHIR context.

Answer (score 0):

It can be added as a medicationCodeableConcept, or you can reference a Medication resource that has that information.
You can find a lot of examples on the specification website: http://www.hl7.org/fhir/medicationrequest-examples.html.
You can also go to https://chat.fhir.org to discuss your usecase and ask how others have done this.